# Asp.net Boilerplate with databaseFirst Approch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-boilerplate

Is it possible to use Asp.net boilerplate with database first approch in ASP.Net MVC? Yes than How?

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking in regard to this [ASP.NET Boilerplate - Web Application Framework](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/), then the answer is **yes**.

Try downloading one of the [sample projects](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Samples) which will all utilize the EF code first approach.